# XNA GameTime Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I have been following the tutorial on Microsofts website and they use GameTime to keep track of a few things. However when I create a new instance, it does not start counting and there is no function like .start() to start the timer. When I run the game the created object gameTime from GameTime remains at 0 for every element inside. Does anyone know how to use GameTime properly because obviously, I am doing it wrong ;)

-Thanks

Comment: I've personally always used asynchronous/multithreaded drawing operations, and have never seen a need for the GameTime class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be creating an instance of the `GameTime` class and instead be using the `gameTime` parameter provided to the `Draw()` and `Update()` methods of the `Game` class:

```
TimeSpan totalGameTime = gameTime.TotalGameTime;
```

A good reference for Windows Phone 7 is [Programming Windows Phone 7](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html), a free e-book by Charles Petzold.

Comment: Even when I put TimeSpan totalGameTime = gameTime.TotalGameTime; in my OnUpdate function, totalGameTime still reads 00:00

Comment: @that_guy for fixed time frame: frame 1 it should read 0. frame 2 it might read 0. frame 3 it reads ~0.016. frame 4 it reads ~0.032... etc.. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, because this is specific to windows phone, you have to use the built in GameTimerEventArgs. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: This does not follow from your original question. If you were having trouble with a specific event, you should have mentioned this in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code for XNA wp game to countdown. I think this can also use in normal XNA
GameTimer for countdown and time count.

```
GameTimer gameTime = new GameTimer();
int _timer = 5;
// initiate
gameTime.UpdateInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);  // game time count every second
gameTime.Update +=new EventHandler<GameTimerEventArgs>(gameTime_Update);  // each time count, will exeute gameTime_Update method.
// each time execute, will decrease _timer by 1
void gameTime_Update(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
{
            _timer-= 1;
}
// on function OnNavigatedTo, after 
timer.Start();  // this is default
gameTime.Start();   // this what I add.
```